# Can KMeans clustering be used on word2vec output?

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset that has been trained on word2vec. Is it a good idea to cluster the output vectors?.

Comment: Don't cluster with the Euclidean distance if you're operating in very high dimensions (typical of word2vec). Use cosine similarity instead. The reason is a bit technical; cf. [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120350/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally fine to cluster word2vec output to know semantically similar words. KMeans is an option, you might also want to checkout some approximate neighbor scheme such as [Locality Sensitive Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Comment: I was also looking at examples where people had taken an average output of the prediction.